# Laravel: Send email to multiple user

Tags: laravel, email

I want to send email in laravel. 2 user get different email content. So, here is my code.

TransactionController.php

```
use App\Mail\MailFruitCustomer;
use App\Mail\MailFruitSeller;

$data = array(
            'fruitid' => 'F01',
            'fruitname' => 'Banana',
            'customercode' => 'B2345',
            'sellercode' => 'S9546'
        );

Mail::to(customer1@mail.com)->send(new MailFruitCustomer($data));
Mail::to(seller1@mail.com)->send(new MailFruitSeller($data));
```

MailFruitCustomer.php (In Mail folder)

```
public function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

public function build(){
    $result = $this->from('admin@mail.com')
                   ->subject('Customer New Transaction')
                   ->markdown('emails/customerreceipt')
                   ->with('data', $this->data);

    return $result;
}
```

MailFruitSeller.php (In Mail folder)

```
public function __construct($data){
        $this->data = $data;
    }

public function build(){
    $result = $this->from('admin@mail.com')
                   ->subject('Seller New Transaction')
                   ->markdown('emails/sellerreceipt')
                   ->with('data', $this->data);

    return $result;
}
```

customerreceipt.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
Customer Receipt Detail
Fruit ID: {{ $data['fruitid'] }}
Fruit Name: {{ $data['fruitname'] }}
Customer Code: {{ $data['customercode'] }}
Thank you.<br>
@endcomponent
```

sellerreceipt.blade.php

```
@component('mail::message')
Seller Receipt Detail
Fruit ID: {{ $data['fruitid'] }}
Fruit Name: {{ $data['fruitname'] }}
Seller Code: {{ $data['sellercode'] }}
Thank you.
@endcomponent
```

It is working and both user get email with different content. But the process take longer time. Is there any method of mail in laravel that i could apply?

Any help will be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for Queues: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues

You create a job that sends the mail and queue the job. Laravel can send the response faster and the Mail is sent asynchronous.

Additional: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#queueing-mail

Answer (score 0):

I continue to learn Queues and create job that sends mail.

I got another problem and fix it with help from others. Thank you.

Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/63370095/12022919.